# Is this use of whomever correct?

Tags: pronouns, grammatical-case, whoever-vs-whomever

> I take pride in my ability to deliver a warm and friendly welcome to whomever I meet.

My reasoning is that I am doing the meeting and the object is merely being met, hence *whomever*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're asking if it's grammatical, it is. It is, however, a painfully formal way of putting it. *Whoever* is what most people, at least in the UK, would use. It's probably better still to avoid that particular word altogether and say something like:

> I take pride in my ability to deliver a warm and friendly welcome to
>   everyone I meet.

Comment: This is a sentence from the opening text of a resume, hence the formality. Do you consider it overly formal? I use British English.

Comment: @BenAston: It's worse than formal. It sounds stilted and pretentious. I bet you don't normally speak like that.

Comment: Hmm, it's grammatically correct. It doesn't sound pretentious to me, just ... correct. I guess pretentiousness is in the ear of the beholder.