# "Whomever" as both object and subject

Tags: pronouns, subjects, objects, whoever-vs-whomever

> I put together a document with my findings in order to help **whomever** keeps working on this.

I understand that "whomever" should be used as an object, whereas "whoever" as a subject. But in the sentence above it seems to be acting as both: object for *help* ("help whomever") and subject for *keep* ("whomever keeps"). In this case, is the sentence above correct?

Also, would it be correct to use "whoever"? Argument would be the same, that it's used both as subject and object.

Comment: Since we rarely say 'whomever' (even for the object), choose 'whoever'.

Comment: "Who(m)ever" keeps working on this" is a noun phrase in a fused relative construction, where it functions as object of  "help". But in the relative clause the pronoun is subject, and hence there is a clash of functions. Despite the clash, subjective "whoever is preferable."

Comment: @BillJ But in other cases, objective seems preferable: to help them that keep working on this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Put me in touch with whomever created it"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/166847/put-me-in-touch-with-whomever-created-it)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is this use of whomever correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56514/is-this-use-of-whomever-correct)

Answer (score 8):

It’s the clause as a whole (whoever keeps working on this) that is the object. Whoever is the subject of that clause. So it should be whoever, not whomever.

Comment: Thers's a clash of functions. The "who(m)ever" expression is not a clause but an NP in a fused relative construction. I agree that it is the object of "help", but within the relative clause fused "whomever" functions as aubject.

Comment: If it were this simple, you would also write _to help they who keep working on this_ or _I who keep working on this_? I think the real answer to this question might be a bit more complicated than it seems at first.

Comment: Not understanding this seems to be a common cause of incorrect overuse of "whom" in US English. In British English, "whom" is virtually obsolete except for set phrases like "To whom it may concern".

Comment: @oerkelens In your example "they" or "I" (which should be "them" or "me" of course) are the direct objects of the main clause, and "who keep working on this" is an adjectival clause (with "who" as its subject) describing the direct object. If you change the sentence to "to help John and Mary who keep working on this" is should be clear that "whom" makes no sense.

Comment: Time to start decluttering. This question is a multi-duplicate. Answering such is unscholarly.

Comment: I agree, @EdwinAshworth, about decluttering, although I think a search function that directs people to questions well-answered is more important than getting rid of clutter.

Comment: If you agree, delete. And D-V and C-V.

Comment: No, @EdwinAshworth, someone has to pick the duplicate. It is a reasonable question. A search for “whomever” has 175 hits. And the OP has not replied to the question whether the suggested possibilities answer his/her/their/its question.

Comment: If you're going to claim this as a better / more apt answer, you should at least sdd a supporting reference.

Answer (score 0):

There is no clash of functions. In the sentence ,"I want to help whoever arrives first","who" is the subject of its own clause, and is in the subjective case. In this sentence, "whomever" would be incorrect.

The complete clause "whoever comes first" is the object of the verb help in the main clause.